# Left/Right function to get number and divide by?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns like so:

```
Column A                       Column B
Number of Points               Number of meetings

15 (15 Pending)                
30 (0 Pending)
```

A user can earn 15 points per meeting which they organise.
I have the points for meetings in my data, but i do not have the number of meetings.

To get the number of meetings and to end up with columns that look like this:

```
Column A                       Column B
Number of Points               Number of meetings

15 (15 Pending)                1 (1 Pending)
30 (0 Pending)                 2 (0 Pending)
```

I have tried to use this formula in column B:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1&"(")-1)/15&" ("&RIGHT(A1,FIND("(",A1&"(")-1)/15&" Pending)"
```

However this produces a #VALUE error.
But if i use just left on its own, like so:

`=LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1&"(")-1)/15`

this gives me a correct value in column B

```
Column A                       Column B
Number of Points               Number of meetings

15 (15 Pending)                1
```

But i also need it to show me the number of pending meetings too.

Not quite sure why the right function won't work but the left function will.
Please can  someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-1)/15 & " (" & MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND("Pending",PROPER(A1))-FIND("(",A1)-1)/15 & " pending)"
```

As with the previous replies, `MID` is the answer.
Since I was working on it, here's my version. It works no matter the case of the word "pending" or the number of spaces you put between the number and "pending" or bracket

Comment: This is definitely the most robust answer

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1&"(")-1)/15&" ("&MID(A1,FIND("(",A1&"(")+1,2)+0&" Pending)"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing RIGHT(A1,FIND("(",A1&"(")-1)/15

With

MID(A1;FIND("(";A1;1)+1;FIND("Pending)";A1;FIND("(";A1;1))-FIND("(";A1;1)-2)/15

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-2)/15&" ("&LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("(",A1)),FIND(" ",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("(",A1)))-1)/15&" Pending)"
```